# Is WPF StackPanel freezable

Tags: wpf, performance, stackpanel

I'm using `StackPanel` in WPF just for easy layouting horizontally aligned boxes and lines, but it seems the performance of application is getting slower when using `StackPanel`.

All the Microsoft tutorials seems to talk only about freezing some `SolidColorBrush` etc. objects, but can StackPanel be freezed after first layout so the CPU doesn't have to layout it all the time, just once?

Or am I just forced to use the very fast `Canvas` object and layout all the objects inside it one by one?

Example 1: Very easy to layout in designer, but lacks performance:

```
    <StackPanel Height="35" Canvas.Left="49" Canvas.Top="874" Width="395" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBox Text="test" Width="65"/>
        <Rectangle Stroke="Black" Width="1" />
        <TextBox Text="test" Width="55"/>
        <Rectangle Stroke="Black" Width="1" />
        <TextBox Text="test" Width="75"/>
        <Rectangle Stroke="Black" Width="1" />
        <TextBox Text="test" Width="35"/>
        <Rectangle Stroke="Black" Width="1" />
        <TextBox Text="test" Width="95"/>
        <Rectangle Stroke="Black" Width="1" />
        <TextBox Text="test" Width="65"/>
        <Rectangle Stroke="Black" Width="1" />
    </StackPanel>
```

Example 2: Good performance, making layout in designer is a pain:

```
    <Canvas Height="35"  Canvas.Left="49" Canvas.Top="914" Width="395">
        <TextBox Text="test" Width="65" Height="35"/>
        <Rectangle Stroke="Black" Width="1" Height="35" Canvas.Left="65"/>
        <TextBox Text="test" Width="55" Canvas.Left="66" Height="35"/>
        <Rectangle Stroke="Black" Width="1" Height="35" Canvas.Left="195"/>
        <TextBox Text="test" Width="75" Height="35" Canvas.Left="122"/>
        <Rectangle Stroke="Black" Width="1" Height="35" Canvas.Left="121"/>
        <TextBox Text="test" Width="35" Height="35" Canvas.Left="198"/>
        <Rectangle Stroke="Black" Width="1" Height="35" Canvas.Left="197"/>
        <TextBox Text="test" Width="95" Height="35" Canvas.Left="234"/>
        <Rectangle Stroke="Black" Width="1" Height="35" Canvas.Left="329"/>
        <TextBox Text="test" Width="65" Height="35" Canvas.Left="330"/>
        <Rectangle Stroke="Black" Width="1" Height="35" Canvas.Left="233"/>         
    </Canvas>
```

Comment: post your XAML. Also if you have large lists with much scrolling you'd be better using `VirtualizingStackPanel` instead.

Comment: No scrolling planned for this - just laying out ~15 textboxes and 1 pixel wide black rectangles in turns side by side. All of these wrapped inside a UserControl, and then about 5-10 of these UserControls in a form.

Comment: 1 - post your XAML. 2 - Please don't call a WPF `Window` a "form". That's an insult to my beliefs and values.

Comment: By "Form" I meant a "fillable form", u know, "an application for job interview" for example :) XAML coming up...

Comment: I copied and pasted your first XAML into a test WPF project and it takes `00:00:00.310` to load. I don't see where the performance issue is. There must be something else. As a side note, why are you using the designer? write the XAML yourself and you'll get much better results.

Comment: Well, actually in my real code the TextBoxes are some usercontrols which I'm not willing to give here.. but anyway, the performance issues arises when my window is rendered at 60fps (scrolling with animation), the stackpanel just can't do the layout at 60fps rate :( But you're totally missing my question here, which was "is `StackPanel` a `Freezable` object"?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25865/discussion-between-highcore-and-jaska)

Answer (score 1):

No, `StackPanel` is not `Freezable`, however you mentioned that your `GPU` is having trouble rendering `Animations` at `60fps`, Try dropping the `Animation` fps

In you main Windows constructor you can override the defualt `framerate` for `Animations`

I usally use 30fps as it is still smooth and users with low-end `GFX` cards will be able to run your application a lot smotther.

Example:

```
    public MainWindow() 
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Timeline.DesiredFrameRateProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(Timeline)
           , new FrameworkPropertyMetadata { DefaultValue = 30 }); // 30 = 30fps
    }
```

Give it a try and see if it helps

Comment: @HighCore already directed me to the right direction - I should use rendertransformations for moving and scaling objects, not the margins and widths and heights and stuff.. So I will try with those.